# listView items disappears on scroll for android 2.3

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

[image] on load of Fragment.
[image] after scrolling smoothly data appears. but again disappera

Android List View on scroll content gets invisible only for 2.3.
working fine for 4.0 and above. 
problem is when I scroll the ListView the data gets disappear and images will be shown only.
If i scroll smoothly and Tap for one or two sec. on list the data will shown but on scroll the data gets disappear.

Below is my adapter code -

```
public class RestaurantListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<RestaurantList> restaurantList;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private Context context;
    private ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    DisplayImageOptions options;

    public RestaurantListAdapter(Activity activity,
            ArrayList<RestaurantList> restaurantList) {
        this.context = activity;
        this.restaurantList = restaurantList;

        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);

        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisc(true).bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).build();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return restaurantList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            convertView = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.restaurant_list_item_layout, null);

            viewHolder.restaurantNameTextView = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.restaurantNameTextView);
            viewHolder.restaurantAddressTextView = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.restaurantAddressTextView);
            viewHolder.restaurantPinTextView = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.restaurantPinTextView);
            viewHolder.restaurantPhoneTextView = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.restaurantPhoneTextView);
            viewHolder.favoriteImageButton = (ImageButton) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.favoriteImageButton);


            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        RestaurantList restaurant = restaurantList.get(position);

        viewHolder.restaurantNameTextView.setText(restaurant
                .getRestaurantName());
        viewHolder.restaurantAddressTextView.setText(restaurant
                .getRestaurantAddress());
        viewHolder.restaurantPinTextView.setText(restaurant.getRestaurantPin());
        viewHolder.restaurantPhoneTextView.setText(restaurant
                .getRestaurantPhone());
        viewHolder.favoriteImageButton.setFocusable(false);

        viewHolder.restaurantNameTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView restaurantNameTextView;
        TextView restaurantAddressTextView;
        TextView restaurantPinTextView;
        TextView restaurantPhoneTextView;
        ImageButton favoriteImageButton;
        ImageView restaurentImageView;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is the data only gone while scrolling or does it stay this way after scrolling? If it is only gone while scrolling, try adding android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" to your ListView.

Comment: My array list data is there  but might be view is gone after scrolling.
if i scroll smoothly the data again appears.
and again disappears on scrolling.
Added android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" but still it is not working.

Comment: Hey i am getting same issue. Do you able to fix this issue if yes, plz help me too... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

simply add

`android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"` to your ListView in your xml layout

Comment: Wesam Torman android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" not working

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect of the line

```
  viewHolder.restaurantNameTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Apparently there is some problem in Android 2.3 about setting the visibility of a view 
(source: http://www.kittehface.com/2011/03/view-visibility-bug-on-android-233.html)

Try to take it off and see what happen...BTW why you are setting the view visible?
Does not seem to be discriminated anywhere....